# Eclipse (Juno) debugger callstack with full qualified class names

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

Is there a way i can display **fully qualified class names** for the debugger's callstack?

E.g. rather than this:

[image]

I would like to have the packages of the classes included - like where the green boxes remain here:

[image]

(NOTE: Actually i dont care where they are displayed as long as there is a easy way to determine the package of a class in the callstack)

**Motivation:**
I am currently working on legacy systems where there is multiple layers of frameworks (both self-made as well as old stuff like Struts 1.1.), service components etc. etc. and i try to figure out the first point our code is included in some way). Since there are now about 100 Projects in my Eclipse -all with their Maven dependencies - things get complicated by just "Link with Editor" and see where the according class is placed in.

**What i tried:**

- Aprox. 20min Webresearch (incl. reading the SO questions/ answers recommended when i created this question) without any remarkable results.
- Using my entire design skills combinated with my 15+ years of MS Paint experience i drew the above images (Feel free to add those stunners to your art collection).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this help?  In the upper right-hand corner of the Debug (callstack) view, click the menu button (the upside down white triangle), then Java, then see the 'Show Qualified Names' option.

[image]